# hawtio remote connect - proxy option not available?

Tags: hawtio, jolokia

Situation:
I would like to connect hawtio to a jolokia agent that is not directly accessible from my browser. I have previously set the proxy flag on the connect / remote tab in such situations. However in this setup there is no such option. Is it removed? Or does it require special configuration to be available?

Details:
The connect -> discovery function is able to detect and show the agents with url.
OS: MacOS Yosemite
hawtio version: 1.4.54
jolokia version: 1.3.1 
Browsers: Chrome 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit) / Firefox 41.0.2 / Safari  9.0.1 (10601.2.7.2)

Further background:

This is part of a docker-compose setup that contains a dedicated hawtio container and several applications that expose the jolokia agent to the hawtio container (and not to the world). As noted above the agent discovery seems to work. However pressing the play button does not work, either it opens a new tab that simply connects to the hawtio VM or it fails.

I am of course open to other solutions:-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I notice that when I connect via link from local tab, discovery tab or remote tab all requests to the target VM go via a local proxy anyway. I assume proxy is now default for connections. Example of proxy URL as seen in Chrome dev tools:

http://localhost:8181/hawtio/proxy/http://127.0.0.1:60760/jolokia/?maxDepth=7&maxCollectionSize=500&ignoreErrors=true&canonicalNaming=false

The proxy flag is therefore no longer necessary.